# Eclipse's content assist do too many things when developing android

Tags: android, eclipse, content-assist

I use eclipse to write android programs as advice by google.

But when I write `import android.` it became `import android.R.anim;.` automatically.

I would like to use content assist, but this behavior is annoying.
How can I modify it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT:

Go into Eclipse -> Preferences

Select Java -> Editor -> Content Assist

In the box in the bottom "Auto-Activation", uncheck the checkbox "Enable Auto-Activation"

See if this helps you. It will disabled the auto-fill, and you will need to press ctrl+space to activate the auto-fill.

If this does not work, then:

By using Eclipse I'd recommend not writing imports where you are importing android-specific classes. Eclipse is smart enough to suggest the classes you need when you need them, organizing your imports automatically.

The only time I ever write the import statements is when I'm importing classes that I've written myself and when Eclipse can not find them.

Let's say you need the class Bitmap from Android.

In your class-file just write:

```
private Bitmap myBitmap;
```

And Eclipse will automatically suggest:

```
android.graphics.Bitmap
```

and import the correct class:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
```

Comment: But similar autocomplete is common. ex. When I write "R.", it becomes "RESULT_CANCELED."

Comment: See my edit. Tweak some of the settings in the Preferences window

Comment: what I really want is: When the cyclic list appears and I press ".", it types "." rather then inserting the first word in list.

Comment: It's useful. Tick.
By the way, I'm not able to use ctrl-space because of my input method. But I can set another combination in Preference->General->Keys. I use tab.